# Suggestion for independent study of mathematical logic

Tags: reference-request, logic, soft-question

Hello I'm looking for advice on mathematical logic books that are good for self-study. I would really like a text that has some if not all of the answers to exercises so I can check my progress as I progress through the text. Any suggestions?

Comment: A.G. Hamilton's *Logic for Mathematicians*

Answer (score 2):

There is an extensive annotated Guide to the literature on mathematical logic at various levels at http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl